# How to configure aad b2c custom policy to use local accounts + other clients

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I need to configure a SignIn (no SignUp) custom policy on an AAD B2C tenant, but I'm lacking the experience of the IEF to design/develop and test it properly. The policy should read (logically) as follows:

1. Present UI to user to enter email only (using a self-asserted TP?)
2. Use custom logic to determine whether the user represents a local account or to any of the known clients of ours. A single client could have multiple possible domains to be authenticated in the same IdP. The only option I know for doing this step is an external REST service, but this is something I would like to avoid if there is any other option to include custom login running inside the custom policy engine, using C#, JS, or event a simple dictionary from email domain to IdP domain.
3. Depending on the IdP automatically selected in step 2, branch to different journeys where the user will be sign-in
4. For local-account sign-in journey, the user will need to use MFA if he/she belongs to admin group. Only email, DisplayName, FirstName, LastName and UserId are needed as final claims.
5. For other IdPs I would have to add ClaimProviders and sub-journeys to allow for signing the users in
6. Finally the JWT Token should be issued to the relying party.

No storing back to AAD storage is required because there is no sign-up process. User are created from the application and invited (if local account) or already exist in their corresponding IdPs.

[image: Overview workflow for the required sign-in logic]

Answer (score 2):

This is another [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern).

It first asks for the domain and then redirects to the appropriate IDP.

To add IDP, refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider).

For MFA, start with the [MFA starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/main/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into the referred samples

Comment: that domain hint example is 3 yrs old.  I'm struggling understanding these xml files but my hunch is that a couple of the references this example file is trying to use, MS no longer has in their base file.

Comment: The problem is that there are different base file e.g. social, local, MFA etc. and they all have additional attributes,

Answer (score 1):

The wording you should look into is "home realm discovery".

There is a custom policy example on [GitHub](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/default-home-realm-discovery). However this example requires the application to provide the email hint. You need to extend it in a way that captures the email in a self-asserted step.

Edit: Sample mentioned by rbrayb better suits your scenario

> For scenarios where you need to implement a sign in journey, where the user is automatically directed to their federated identity provider based off of their email domain. And for users who arrive with an unknown domain, they are redirected to a default identity provider.
>
> In this example, users who enter an email with the suffix contoso.com, they will be redirected directly to their federated identity provider to sign in. In this case that is Azure AD (SAML2).
>
> Users who enter an email with the suffix facebook.com, they will be redirected directly to their federated identity provider to sign in. In this case that is Facebook (OAuth).
>
> Where a user comes from an unknown email suffix, they will be redirected directly to a default identity provider, in this case that is Azure AD (OpenId).

Comment: Thanks! I saw that expression [home realm discovery](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/auth0-universal-login/identifier-first#define-home-realm-discovery-identity-providers) in Auth0 docs. I already created a Azure Function o receive the email claim and return an idp claim. I'm missing the self-asserted UI to capture the email, but still looking through samples for that.